# Working and not Data Annotation inheritance in ViewModels

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvvm

One question about ASP / MVC 2 Data Annotations.
I have ViewModels with inheritance:

```
public class CategoryModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "XName")]
        //[DisplayName("XXX")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CategoryListModel : CategoryModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "WName")]
        //[DisplayName("WWW")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public new string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in Controller:

```
public ActionResult List()
        {
            CategoryListModel model = new CategoryListModel();
            return View(model);
        }
```

And then in typed View:

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Name)%>
```

**Why [Display(Name="SomeName")] does not work, neither in base model nor inherited one?**
Meanwhile [DisplayName("SomeName")] works fine including inheritance ...

Thanks, Art